# Setting a label in a thread causes IllegalStateException

Tags: multithreading, blackberry, java-me, illegalstateexception

I have a thread like:

```
    startButton.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
        public void fieldChanged(Field arg0, int arg1) {

                    Thread thread = new Thread(){
                        public void run() {
                            uploadFile();
                        }
                    };
                    thread.start();
                }
            //});

    });
```

The `uploadFile` method contains the line `label_up_result.setText(result);` which causes an `IllegalStateException`.

`label_up_result` is defined like: `final LabelField label_up_result=new LabelField("", LabelField.FIELD_LEFT);`

What can be the problem ? How can I fix it ?

Comment: Please show the first couple line of the exception and the first couple of lines of _all_ cause sections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is probably that you are trying to update the UI from a worker thread. There are two approaches. You can synchronize on the event lock:

```
synchronized(UiApplication.getUiApplication().getEventLock())) {
    label_up_result.setText(result);
}
```

or you can create a `Runnable` to execute on the UI thread:

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        label_up_result.setText(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: I want to be able to leave screen and come back freely while the thread is running.  I tried them but it doesnt look like they will let me do that unless I am doing something wrong

Comment: @Cemre - Are you still getting an IllegalStateException with the code I suggested, or is there another problem?

Comment: No I am not getting any problems it works fine. However, the screen becomes locked while the process is going on. I want to be able to leave the screen and do other things while the thread is doing its job (Since it is a long running task). What I am wondering is if there is a way to prevent this. But otherwise your solution is fine thanks so much.

Comment: @Cemre - If you are using the first method (synchronizing on the event lock), make sure that you hold the lock for as brief a time as possible. If you put all your background processing inside the synchronized block, that would explain why the screen becomes locked.

Comment: I only lock when setting the text field as you suugested and it seems to work. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score -2):

I don't know about blackberry, but usually you need to perform the ui-actions in the ui-thread. `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` provides that functionality in JavaSE, http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Swinginvokelater.htm